# Solr performance degrades and Solr becomes unresponsive

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, solr

We have a Solr cluster composed of 3 Solr nodes/services.
They run in 3 separate EC2 AWS instances/boxes.

On each of the 3 EC2 boxes there's also a ZooKeeper instance running. So on each EC2 box we have 1 solr and 1 ZooKeeper service up.

OK, also these 3 EC2 instances are in the us-east-1a, us-east-1b, us-east-1c AWS availability zones.

Some more details:

**Linux 6.2.0-1018-aws, 4cpu

Memory: 30.9Gb

Java 11.0.21

Solr 9.1.0**

1. Is this setup OK? Do you see any general issues with it?
   I am not sure e.g. if the 3 EC2 boxes being in 3 different
   availability zones is OK.
2. Sometimes when we issue queries to this Solr cluster, the Solr cluster becomes unresponsive and requests just start timing out or Solr starts behaving very slow. At that moment, on the client side we see errors like e.g. `504 Gateway Time-out`. Also at that moment, when I check the Solr server logs, I see interesting things like this.

   ```
   2024-02-12 16:32:32.171 ERROR (updateExecutor-8-thread-5607-processing-10.9.10.136:8983_solr calls_shard2_replica_n2 calls shard2 core_node5) [c:calls s:shard2 r:core_node5 x:calls_shard2_replica_n2] o.a.s.u.SolrCmdDistributor org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
    => org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
   2024-02-12 16:32:32.171 WARN  (qtp26757919-22512) [c:calls s:shard2 r:core_node5 x:calls_shard2_replica_n2] o.a.s.u.p.DistributedZkUpdateProcessor Error sending update to http://10.9.13.144:8983/solr => org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
   2024-02-12 16:32:32.172 WARN  (updateExecutor-8-thread-5597-processing-form_fills_shard2_replica_n6 core_node9 null 10.9.10.136:8983_solr form_fills shard2) [c:form_fills s:shard2 r:core_node9 x:form_fills_shard2_replica_n6] o.a.s.c.s.i.ConcurrentUpdateHttp2SolrClient Failed to parse error response from http://10.9.13.144:8983/solr/form_fills_shard2_replica_n2/ due to:  => java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version (expected 2, but 60) or the data in not in 'javabin' format
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version (expected 2, but 60) or the data in not in 'javabin' format
   2024-02-12 16:32:32.172 ERROR (updateExecutor-8-thread-5597-processing-form_fills_shard2_replica_n6 core_node9 null 10.9.10.136:8983_solr form_fills shard2) [c:form_fills s:shard2 r:core_node9 x:form_fills_shard2_replica_n6] o.a.s.u.ErrorReportingConcurrentUpdateSolrClient Error when calling SolrCmdDistributor$Req: cmd=add{_version_=1790711473813585920,id=205656127_20240212_web_1707755535}; node=StdNode: http://10.9.13.144:8983/solr/form_fills_shard2_replica_n2/ to http://10.9.13.144:8983/solr/form_fills_shard2_replica_n2/ => org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://10.9.13.144:8983/solr/form_fills_shard2_replica_n2/: null
   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://10.9.13.144:8983/solr/form_fills_shard2_replica_n2/: null
   2024-02-12 16:32:32.173 WARN  (qtp26757919-22558) [c:calls s:shard3 r:core_node3 x:calls_shard3_replica_n1] o.a.s.u.p.DistributedZkUpdateProcessor Error sending update to http://10.9.13.144:8983/solr => org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
   2024-02-12 16:32:32.173 WARN  (qtp26757919-22540) [c:calls s:shard2 r:core_node5 x:calls_shard2_replica_n2] o.a.s.u.p.DistributedZkUpdateProcessor Error sending update to http://10.9.13.144:8983/solr => org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
   2024-02-12 16:32:32.174 WARN  (qtp26757919-22559) [c:calls s:shard3 r:core_node3 x:calls_shard3_replica_n1] o.a.s.u.p.DistributedZkUpdateProcessor Error sending update to http://10.9.13.144:8983/solr => org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at null: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
   2024-02-12 16:32:32.175 WARN  (updateExecutor-8-thread-5599-processing-calls_shard2_replica_n2 core_node5 null 10.9.10.136:8983_solr calls shard2) [c:calls s:shard2 r:core_node5 x:calls_shard2_replica_n2] o.a.s.c.s.i.ConcurrentUpdateHttp2SolrClient Failed to parse error response from http://10.9.13.144:8983/solr/calls_shard1_replica_n10/ due to:  => java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version (expected 2, but 60) or the data in not in 'javabin' format
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version (expected 2, but 60) or the data in not in 'javabin' format
   ```

We start seeing these errors when we start issuing heavy queries to Solr (like e.g. give me 10K rows which match certain condition). If we run the same query/condition but we say give me just 100 rows, then Solr behaves OK, I don't think it falls in that bad state.

So it's quite an interesting situation.

I am new to Solr but bases on what I am seeing, I have the feeling our Solr nodes are losing connectivity between each other, or between each other and the 3 ZooKeeper instances. Am I thinking in the right direction? What can be done to solve this issue?

Any hints or advices are most welcome here!

Comment: The `text/html` error indicates that the container responds with an error in those cases (i.e. the container responds with a jetty error instead of the regular javabin format that the Solr nodes expect between them selves); does it always happen with `.144`? It might be helpful to look at the local log for that node instead of what the federating Solr server says.

Comment: @MatsLindh It happens with any node at random, not just with .144. In this particular case it's .144, but sometimes it's another node. I also think the nodes are somehow miscommunicating but I cannot figure out anything more specific.

Comment: Have you check the actual log for the node that's returning the wrong response content when it happens? Can it be that it happens because of an external factor such as a load balancer/routing/reverse proxy that has a timing limitation? for example that the aws front server terminates the request because it runs for too long? In that case you wouldn't have a local error on the other node, since the problem happens between the servers. You should be able to attach a debugger to the location in the stack trace and dump the stack when it happens and look at the actual response content.